# h.264 HTML5 Video isn't working in IE 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-video

Please visit https://mediacru.sh/demo for a live demonstration of this problem. It works fine in Chrome, Chromium, Safari, Firefox, and Opera, as well as mobile versions of these browsers.

Comment: contact the author for IE 10 issues.

Comment: My IE 10 displays the video (not the gif) in that website.

Comment: Here it displays both the GIF and the video. Do you get an error or something?

Comment: I get no errors. I am the author of this website.